# Can I use a key on an attribute of a node which is under a variable?

Tags: xml, xslt, indexing

I have a large chunk of XML sitting inside a variable in my XSLT. Here is the overiew:

```
....
<xsl:variable name="node_clone">
  <xsl:call-template name="node_content"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($node_clone)/*">

<xsl:template name="node_content">
  <xsl:copy-of select"exsl:node-set($dummy_container)//sometag[someatr='..']">
<xsl:template>

...

<xsl:variable name="dummy_container">
  <big_chunk_of_xml>
    ...
    <!--THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO ACCESS FAST -->
    <sometag someatr="value">....

  </big_chunk_of_xml>
</xsl>
```

This code takes an element from within a chunk of xml in a variable (dummy_container), clones it and calls a template on it.

This will happen many times and the big chunk of xml in the dummy_container will be accessed many times. Can I use key() on sometag's someatr to make this faster?

The way the calls work may not make sense, it has been simplified to focus on the real issue: indexing. So please do not get stuck on what is being done here. I'm using XSLT 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a key and make the search:

```
<xsl:key name="k1" match="sometag[@someatr]" use="@someatr"/>


<xsl:variable name="lkp-doc" select="exsl:node-set($dummy-container)"/>

<xsl:template name="node-content">
  <xsl:param name="value"/>
  <!-- need to change context document here to make sure the key function
       works with the right document -->
  <xsl:for-each select="$lkp-doc">
    <xsl:copy-of select="key('k1', $value)"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Sorry, my code does not show up but somehow Firefox for Android on my tablet and stackoverflow code editing does not work. Perhaps someone can edit and ensure the code is shown, otherwise I will try tomorrow when I will be back at some real desktop pc. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I can see that the trick is to change the context. I'll use the for-each within my node_content template, which should then use the key when dummy_container is used. It looks like it should work. Nice trick!